# printing a doc file using cocoa

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I'm looking for a simple code to print the contents of a MS Word file (.doc, .docx) using Cocoa. I'm a newbie to Cocoa. Someone please help.

Comment: On OS X(Mac) ? or on iOS (iPhone/iPad/iPod Touch)?

Answer (score 1):

Mac OS? Doc format is supported by NSAttributedString, which means it can be opened in an NSTextView. You print a doc file the same as you print most other text/rich text files. You can do it with an off-screen text view if you don't want to force the user to view it before printing.

There is some good [example code for printing from an off-screen NSTextView](http://www.cocoadev.com/index.pl?NSTextViewPrinting) on the CocoaDev wiki.